# Getting No Output When INNER JOIN Is Used Twice In A Query

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to SQL Join topic. I don't know why my SQL Query is not working properly. Here is the query:

```
SELECT * from post
  INNER JOIN user ON post.id = user.id
  INNER JOIN follower ON user.id= follower.id
  WHERE follower.fid = 20 OR user.id < 1000
  ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 7
```

If I use this query it works:

```
SELECT * from post
  INNER JOIN user ON post.id = user.id
  WHERE user.id < 1000
  ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 7
```

But adding another INNER JOIN gave no output.

**Update :**

I am using 2 INNER JOINS so that I can show data from 3 table if there are no followers in follower table then show data from 2 tables(post and user) only where id in user table is less then 1000.

Comment: Define "works". What are you expecting it to do? What *does* it do?

Comment: Can you give examples on what the data in the 3 tables look like?

Comment: When you use the second INNER JOIN, you will get only results where you have matches in both user and follower. If you want to get data from user when follower does not match, you should use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thanks @ Linkan .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you probably have no `follower` on the `post`:

```
SELECT * from post
INNER JOIN user ON post.id = user.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN follower ON user.id= follower.id -- changed JOIN type
WHERE follower.fid = 20 OR user.id < 1000
ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 7
```

Remember `INNER JOIN` only returns if it finds the match in all JOIN conditions. Any condition will fail and you won't get the row.

**For example:**
You have a post, but the `user` has no `follower`. `INNER JOIN` will skip the row. Here comes the `OUTER JOIN`! it will give you the `user` row even when no `follower` is found.

Comment: why Left join is used ?

Comment: @Shaharyar you've forgotten something

Comment: LEFT JOIN x WHERE x... is the same as INNER JOIN x...  The caveat is the OR clause which acts on the user table - but I never use that on an OUTER JOIN because I don't understand it.

Comment: I would remove `follower.fid = 20` but I didn't know the schema so I kept it to OP response, and as the OP has got the expected output. Its fine though